# Error on Angular App: error TS2307: Cannot find module

Tags: javascript, angular, amazon-web-services, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

I am working on an Angular App.  It can build and run locally but when I deploy to AWS CodeBuild and try and build it there, I get these messages:

```
[0m[1m[31mERROR in src/app/sos-api/api/authentication.service.ts(20,49): error TS2307: Cannot find module '../model/authenticateRefreshTokenCommand'.[39m[22m[0m
[0m[1m[31msrc/app/sos-api/api/authentication.service.ts(21,41): error TS2307: Cannot find module '../model/authenticateUserCommand'.[39m[22m[0m
[0m[1m[31msrc/app/sos-api/api/organization.service.ts(20,43): error TS2307: Cannot find module '../model/createOrganizationCommand'.[39m[22m[0m
[0m[1m[31msrc/app/sos-api/api/organization.service.ts(21,49): error TS2307: Cannot find module '../model/createOrganizationCommandResult'.[39m[22m[0m
[0m[1m[31msrc/app/sos-api/api/organization.service.ts(22,43): error TS2307: Cannot find module '../model/deleteOrganizationCommand'.[39m[22m[0m
[0m[1m[31msrc/app/sos-api/api/organization.service.ts(23,49): error TS2307: Cannot find module '../model/deleteOrganizationCommandResult'.[39m[22m[0m
[0m[1m[31msrc/app/sos-api/api/organization.service.ts(24,42): error TS2307: Cannot find module '../model/listOrganizationsCommand'.[39m[22m[0m
[0m[1m[31msrc/app/sos-api/api/organization.service.ts(25,48): error TS2307: Cannot find module '../model/listOrganizationsCommandResult'.[39m[22m[0m
[0m[1m[31msrc/app/sos-api/api/organization.service.ts(26,47): error TS2307: Cannot find module '../model/readOrganizationCommandResult'.[39m[22m[0m
[0m[1m[31msrc/app/sos-api/api/organization.service.ts(27,43): error TS2307: Cannot find module '../model/updateOrganizationCommand'.[39m[22m[0m
[0m[1m[31msrc/app/sos-api/api/organization.service.ts(28,49): error TS2307: Cannot find module '../model/updateOrganizationCommandResult'.[39m[22m[0m
[0m[1m[31msrc/app/sos-api/model/createChecklistCommandResult.ts(12,26): error TS2307: Cannot find module './metadata'.[39m[22m[0m
[0m[1m[31msrc/app/sos-api/model/createCourseCommandResult.ts(12,26): error TS2307: Cannot find module './metadata'.[39m[22m[0m
[0m[1m[31msrc/app/sos-api/model/createLabRequestCommandResult.ts(12,26): error TS2307: Cannot find module './metadata'.[39m[22m[0m
[0m[1m[31msrc/app/sos-api/model/createPatientCommandResult.ts(12,26): error TS2307: Cannot find module './metadata'.[39m[22m[0m
```

Here is some information about my configuration:

```
Angular CLI: 1.6.3
Node: 8.6.0
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 5.1.3
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

@angular/cli: 1.6.3
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer: 0.0.36
@angular-devkit/core: 0.0.22
@angular-devkit/schematics: 0.0.42
@ngtools/json-schema: 1.1.0
@ngtools/webpack: 1.9.3
@schematics/angular: 0.1.11
@schematics/schematics: 0.0.11
typescript: 2.4.2
webpack: 3.10.0
```

Comment: error is coming in model and api folder. Please check corresponding folder or post more information.

Comment: Yes, I can see that.  But not sure why.  What information do you need?

Comment: Can I see your tsconfig.json file?